# How to make the toolbar click-region larger?

Tags: windows-10

I have started moving some less used task bar programs to toolbars. However, the clickable region to open them up is so tiny, it's not even worth the space saving payoff:

[image]

---

## Is there an extension or something that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the taskbar and unselect "lock the taskbar".

[image]

Now you can resize the toolbars.

Comment: That doesn't make the clickable region any larger. I can make it larger, but it just puts the apps in my task bar. I want to have that region that opens the folder contents to be larger.

Comment: explain this more in detail. I have no idea what you want to make larger

Comment: ok, I see the update. this is not possible in windows.

Comment: I agree, notice there's this at the end: "Is there an extension that will allow me to do this?"

Comment: since Windows 7, Microsoft removed floating Deskbands so I doubt that any 3rd party tool can implement this feature.